# How to enable tilestache-seed logging?

Tags: tilestache

We're migrating from a working 'tilecache' server to a new 'tilestache' server.

I have been chasing my tail for 2 days now trying to figure out how to get tilestache-seed to cache some tiles. I'm failing miserably and neither the tilestache docs nor google are helping at all. It must be me.

I have a configuration that looks like this:

```
{
    "cache": {
        "name": "Disk",
        "path": "/opt/tiles",
        "umask": "0000",
        "dirs": "safe"
    },
    "logging": "debug",
    "layers": {
        "staging": {
            "provider": {
                "name": "url template",
                "template": "http://example.com/common/services/imagegen/?mapservice=cities&cs=102113&crs=102113&layers=6&format=png&bbox=$xmin,$ymin,$xmax,$ymax"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A typical tilestache-seed command line looks like this

```
./seed -c tilestache.json -l staging -b -65.167510000 47.589390000 -65.167490000 47.589410000
```

Note: `seed` is a symlink to `tilecache-seed.py` - PIA to type the full path so much :)

Note also that 'imagegen' is a proprietary application that sits in front of ArcIMS to manage other things about the image generation. Nothing magic, just additional capability that is irrelevant in this particular case.

Running the command line and *nothing* at all happens. No output at all from tilestache-seed. It is not making a call to the URL in the config file - I can see that because imagegen writes the generated image to an output directory on the web server, and there's nothing being written in response to seed being run.

If I manually massage the seed command line and substituting the -b parameters into the proper spots in the URL and paste that in a browser, I generate an image just fine.

So why isn't seed doing what I think it should be doing?

I figure there must be a way to see what's going on inside seed. Well, no command line option to turn on "verbose" mode. Ah, I can use the Test cache and turn on verbose there. No, that changes nothing - no output of any sort.

Note that the example in the tilestache docs for the Test cache appears to be in error:

```
"verbose": True
```

throws an error when running seed.

```
"verbose": true
```

fixes the error, but doesn't generate any additional output.

Can someone provide me guidance, please, on a) what might be wrong with my configuration and/or b) how to turn on some sort of diagnostic mode so that I can debug this further? I'm not a python guy, though that's a skill I probably ought to acquire.

Thanks!

Bo

PS: Any reference to 'tilecache' should read 'tilestache' - been typing the former for too many years :)